# C++ compiler that runs on Windows10IoT on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I want to compile C++ programs directly on Windows 10IoT for Raspberry Pi 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to compile them on the Pi itself rather than compile them on a PC and deploy them to the Pi?

Comment: Visual C++ targets Windows IoT devices and you'll find a few samples in the [Windows IoT site](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/StartCoding.htm).

Comment: I actually wish to setup a compiler farm using them. I wanted to install the standard C++ compiler that comes with Visual Studio Express. Obviously Windows 10 IoT is some variant on Windows RT so Id need an ARM version of the compiler which compiles for x64.